# Java: Create CSV from Get Array with Object

Tags: java

I have

```
data= [{
          id=1, 
          employee_name=Tiger Nixon, 
          employee_salary=320800, 
          employee_age=61, 
          profile_image=
       }, 
       {
          id=2, 
          employee_name=Garrett Winters, 
          employee_salary=170750, 
          employee_age=63, 
          profile_image=
       }, 
       {
          id=3, 
          employee_name=Ashton Cox, 
          employee_salary=86000, 
          employee_age=66, 
          profile_image=
       }, 
       {
          id=4, 
          employee_name=Cedric Kelly, 
          employee_salary=433060, 
          employee_age=22, 
          profile_image=
       }
      ]
```

I have employee class

```
public class Employee {
    private String employee_name;
    private String employee_salary;
    private String employee_age;
    private String id;
    private String profile_image;

    public String toCsvRow() {
        String csvRow = "";
        for (String value : Arrays.asList(employee_name,employee_salary,employee_age)) {
            String processed = value;
            if (value.contains("\"") || value.contains(",")) {
                processed = "\"" + value.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
            }
            csvRow += "," + processed;
        }
        return csvRow.substring(1);
    }

    public String getEmployee_name() {
        return employee_name;
    }

    public String getEmployee_salary() {
        return employee_salary;
    }

    public String getEmployee_age() {
        return employee_age;
    }          
}
```

I tried for

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Employee>> map = mapper.readValue(url, Map.class);
ArrayList<Employee> emps = map.get("data");
emps.get(0).toCsvRow()

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.example.model.Employee
```

Now I cannot call toCSVRow using emps.

Comment: It’s not clear what your asking and what your issue is. Is there a problem with `map` or with converting the content of it to a list of Employee objects?

Comment: First thing I don't understand is this `Arrays.asList(employee_name,employee_salary,employee_age)`, shouldn't it be expecting an array? Second is do you want to create a excel file or store it to a variable named `csvRow`

Comment: yes I want it to store in csv format

Comment: update the question I want csv from this employee data

Comment: I think it should be `Map<String, ArrayList<Employee>> map = mapper.readValue(data, new TypeReference<Map<String,ArrayList<Employee>>>(){});`rather than `Map<String, ArrayList<Employee>> map = mapper.readValue(url, Map.class);`. Read Map from JSON String reference : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html

Comment: What line generates the error, I can't see any code where a cast might occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to parse JSON to ArrayList, for CSV conversion you can use [org.json.CDL](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107)

See this is working fine

```java
String str = "[{" +
            "          id=1," +
            "          employee_name=\"Tiger Nixon\"," +
            "          employee_salary=320800," +
            "          employee_age=61," +
            "          profile_image=\"khkjh\"" +
            "       }," +
            "       {" +
            "          id=2," +
            "          employee_name=\"Garrett Winters\"," +
            "          employee_salary=170750," +
            "          employee_age=63," +
            "          profile_image=\"\"" +
            "       }," +
            "       {" +
            "          id=3," +
            "          employee_name=\"Ashton Cox\"," +
            "          employee_salary=86000," +
            "          employee_age=66," +
            "          profile_image=\"\"" +
            "       }," +
            "       {" +
            "          id=4," +
            "          employee_name=\"Cedric Kelly\"," +
            "          employee_salary=433060," +
            "          employee_age=22," +
            "          profile_image=\"\"" +
            "       }" +
            "      ]";


         try{

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ArrayList<Employee> list = gson.fromJson(str, ArrayList.class);

            String csv = CDL.toString(new JSONArray(list));

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Output:

```
id,employee_name,employee_salary,employee_age,profile_image
    1.0,Tiger Nixon,320800.0,61.0,khkjh
    2.0,Garrett Winters,170750.0,63.0,
    3.0,Ashton Cox,86000.0,66.0,
    4.0,Cedric Kelly,433060.0,22.0
```